# How to determine whether a process handle is of the current process?

Tags: windows, winapi

I have a `HANDLE` to a process, which might, or might not, be the handle of the currently running process. The following is known about the handle object:

1. The handle only has the `PROCESS_TERMINATE` access right.
2. The handle is not a pseudo-handle, i.e. not the return value of `GetCurrentProcess`.

Is there a way to know whether the handle is of the current process?

I thought about using `GetProcessId`, but unfortunately it fails with an access denied error, because the handle doesn't have the `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` access right.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate; the fact that the handle has only terminate access is relevant.  Voting to reopen.

Comment: Try using `DuplicateHandle` to create a new handle with `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` right.  (If access is denied, it is unlikely to be a handle to your process - though if you want to be safe, you could check the ACL on the running process and change it if necessary.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston thanks, I'll try it. Is there any documentation as of when does `DuplicateHandle` allow to add additional access rights? The documentation of the function states the following, which is not very helpful: "In some cases, the new handle can have more access rights than the original handle. However, in other cases, `DuplicateHandle` cannot create a handle with more access rights than the original."

Comment: Based on the example they gave, I believe I understand the reason why it sometimes isn't possible, and it doesn't apply to process handles.  I believe you'll only be unable to gain new access rights if you don't have the corresponding permissions to the target process.

Comment: @HarryJohnston the `DuplicateHandle` method works, thanks!
Feel free to post an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have sufficient access to the target process, you can create a new handle to it with the `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` access right by using [DuplicateHandle()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724251(v=vs.85).aspx).  You can then use this handle to get the process ID.

Unless your process modifies its own security permissions, it should always have (at least) `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` access to itself, so if duplicating the handle fails with an access denied error it is unlikely that the handle points to your process.

If you want to make absolutely certain, you can try opening a handle to your process by process ID - if that fails then someone is messing with the ACL and all bets are off. :-)